# Uitableviewcontroller with two sections

Tags: swift, uitableview

In my UITableViewController, I have two sections.
In I can select only one item from section 1 but 1 or more from section 2. I implemented Cell Accessory type to toggle between .CheckMark and .None

I cannot get it to have 1 selection for section 1 but multi selection for section 2.

Any idea  how to implement these perhaps with
tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) and tableView(tableView: UITableView, didRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this task following the below approach.

Take a global variable and an array. Save required values at didSelectRowAtIndexPath and reload the table. I am sharing the demo project for the same. I have created and tested it. Its working fine. Here is the link: [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwftp_LIDNUQUTBsUnlJSVpENEE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you please mark it as correct? We can definitely reload just the cells in place of reloading the full table using "reloadRowsAtIndexPaths". That shouldn't be expensive now :).

Answer (score 0):

One idea can be you set `self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;` property in the tableview

Store the section 1 selection value in a variable 
 
Section 2 value in array

In the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you check for the section and if it's section 1 remove/deselect the previous one value stored in the variable one and select/store the new one

If it's section 2 you can select/deselect the selected value in array and on cell by UITableViewCellAccessoryType

```
if (cell?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark){

    cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None;

}else{

    cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark;

}
```

If you want you may remove the value in both the section in `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`, but that may not require if you write select/deselect code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`